# Merge HTML content from two paragraphs with lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

I would like to merge all the content from two paragraphs into one single paragraph, with a space between them. How could I do this using lxml?

Example:

```
<p>He is <b>bold</b>!</p>
<p>Is he <u>here</u>?</p>
```

Would be merged into:

```
<p>He is <b>bold</b>! Is he <u>here</u>?</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your structure is simple, this might do the trick:

```py
import lxml
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("<root></root>")
first = etree.fromstring("<p>He is <b>bold</b>!</p>")
second = etree.fromstring("<p>Is he <u>here</u>?</p>")
try:
    first.getchildren()[-1].tail += ' ' + second.text
except IndexError:
    first.text += ' ' + second.text
root.append(first)
for child in second.getchildren():
    root.append(child)
etree.tostring(root)
```